# WHY ORA-00905: missing keyword issue occurs during create table or view in Oracle

Tags: oracle10g, create-table, create-view

This issue occurs due to the table name or view name is not valid as per the permissible text. 
For example create table with table name 'EMPLOYEE-DETAIL' is not valid due to it contains hyphen '-'; so use underscore '_' instead of hyphen. Like EMPLOYEE_DETAIL.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Looks like an answer to someone else's question, @Seb.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs due to the table name or view name is not valid as per the permissible text. For example create table with table name 'EMPLOYEE-DETAIL' is not valid due to it contains hyphen '-'; so use underscore '_' instead of hyphen. Like EMPLOYEE_DETAIL.